# Multiple Objects of pojo class in 1 html form spring mvc?

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, spring-mvc

i am working with Spring where my form fields are same with attribute fields so when i submit form it directly maps to database fields and save the data it works perfectly, but what if i want to save multiple  objects with one form,

HTML:

```
<form>
  Payment:<br>
  <input type="text" name="payment"><br>
  Date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="paymentDate">
</form>
```

POJO:

```
public class ProjectPayment
{
    private Double payment;
    private Date paymentDate;
    // setters and getters
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addnewproject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public @ResponseBody String SaveProject(ProjectPayment projectPayment) {
     projectPaymentService.saveProjectPayment( projectPayment);
}
```

this works perfectly,
but now in my some scenario i need multiple objects dynamically then how to save in database, how controller should look like

for example:

Now my Form is

```
<form>
  Payment:<br>
  <input type="text" name="payment"><br>
  Date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="paymentDate">
Payment:<br>
  <input type="text" name="payment"><br>
  Date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="paymentDate">
Payment:<br>
  <input type="text" name="payment"><br>
  Date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="paymentDate">
Payment:<br>
  <input type="text" name="payment"><br>
  Date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="paymentDate">
</form>
```

Now this form have multiple objects of ProjectPayment class but it saves only one object
please tell me how my controller should like, i have done like this but it occurs exception

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addnewproject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public @ResponseBody String SaveProject(ProjectPayment[] projectPayment) {
     for(ProjectPayment propay : projectPayment)
        {
            projectPaymentService.saveProjectPayment( propay );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can understand that you want to post data from a grid/table, however it's too ambiguous to determine which field map to which object.
Example:

> - field1
> - field2
> - **field3** ==>Map to object at index 1 or 2?
> - filed1

So you think field3 should map to array index=1 or index=2?
So I suggest you should submit one by one to solve this issue.

Comment: in my scenario i need multiple objects with one form, so i cannot save one by one

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to solve this problem is create a ViewModel.

e.g.

```
public class ProjectPaymentViewModel
{
  private List<ProjectPayment> listProjectPayment;    
  // setters and getters
}
```

Use this view model on web page and controller

```
<form>
 Payment:<br>
 <input type="text" name="listProjectPayment[0].payment"><br>
 Date:<br>
 <input type="date" name="listProjectPayment[0].paymentDate">
 Payment:<br>
 <input type="text" name="listProjectPayment[1].payment"><br>
 Date:<br>
 <input type="date" name="listProjectPayment[1].paymentDate">
 Payment:<br>

</form>
```

On controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addnewproject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody String SaveProject(ProjectPaymentViewModel projectPaymentViewModel) {
 for(ProjectPayment propay : projectPaymentViewModel.getListProjectPayment())
    {
        projectPaymentService.saveProjectPayment( propay );
        }
}
```